# In angular reactive forms, is there anything wrong in placing non-input html elements inside a html form tag?

Tags: html, angular

If you're using an angular reactive form for handling html inputs, is there any problem in placing non-input html elements in the `form` tags?

EDIT: Removed bad example, will update new one later

Comment: nothing at all. no answer to give here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. The form is in fact defined to contain any flow [flow-element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20121025/common-models.html#common.elem.flow).

Check the official documentation for form elements, what is allowed inside:

```
The form element represents a user-submittable form.
...
Permitted contents    
    Flow content
```

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20121025/form.html#form

Flow content is defined to `consists of flow elements intermixed with normal character data.` 
Soruce: https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20121025/terminology.html#flow-content

And a list is here:
https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20121025/common-models.html#common.elem.flow

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with non-input elements inside a form or angular reactive form.

Answer (score 0):

It's completely fine to do so, in your example the only thing that matters is the correct usage of **formGroup** and **formControlName** and matching those parameters to the actual form structure.